# Vector de numeros aleatorios en parejas c++

Tags: c++, array

necesito crear un programa en c++ que rellene un vector de 16 posiciones de numeros aleatorios en parejas.
El rango de los numeros aleatorios debe ser 0-7, por lo que un ejemplo del vector sería:
0 3 5 0 6 3 1 7 1 2 7 6 4 4 2 5

Solo puedo hacer uso de la función rand()
Alguna idea?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor, consulta [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Muestra un [mcve] e indica cual es el problema puntual que te has encontrado. Tal y como lo planteas, parece que pides que hagan el trabajo **para ti**. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, lleva varios días dándole vueltas y no consigo llegar a implementarlo. Mi idea para generar las parejas de aleatorios es crear un vector de 8 posiciones y cada vez que genere un número, incrementar un contador en esa misma poscion hasta llegar a 2, y en caso de que genere un número y en esa posisión ya haya un dos, vuelva a generar otro número. Estoy empezando a programar y tampoco tengo mucha idea de como poder hacer eso. Un saludo

Comment: Por favor, [edita tu pregunta pulsando este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/412589/edit) y añade ahí toda la información relevante. No obstante, me parece que sin mostrar un [mcve], tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero creas el vector y una variable

```
vector<int> mivector;
int mivariablerand;
```

Luego crea un for de 16 donde la variable mivariablerand le asignas un rand de 0 a 7
Y luego le haces un pushback para asignarlo al vector

```
mivector.pushback(mivariablerand);
```

en el mismo for para printearlos creo que podria hacerlo con .at();

```
const int& variableparaprintear = mivector.at(variabledelfor);
cout << variableparaprintear << " ";
```

Toma el codigo que dije , resuelve los problemas y crea el programa

Espero que te sirva y te haya respondido tu pregunta correctamente